# How to convert string of array into array in php

Tags: php

I have a string like below:

```
$arrayString = "[Orange,Apple,Grape]";
```

How can I convert this into an Array?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `str_replace` replacing square brackets because they might be replaced in the array string, so let's `trim` them instead, and explode the list on the commas. Given your sample above, this will produce an array of strings.

```
$arrayString = "[Orange,Apple,Grape]";

print_r( explode(",", trim($arrayString, "][")) );
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Orange
    [1] => Apple
    [2] => Grape
)
```

Note: If you have escaped commas, then this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps should do it.

```
$arrayString = "[Orange,Apple,Grape]";
$array=explode( ',', str_replace( array('"','[',']'), '', $arrayString ) );
```

Comment: What if there is a `[` or `]` within a string?